# Connecting Android Tablet to WAMP server

Tags: android, apache, android-asynctask, wamp

I am working on a WAMP server. I have a db_connect.php file residing on the server. I make a http request for this file from my android device which is connected to the computer via the usb cable.

However every time I request the file I get the following error:

**Error in Connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://x.x.x.x refused**

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I have the desktop running WAMP on my home broadband and my tablet connected to my home broadband.

if I change the post request to contact www.google.com I establish connection. Any suggestions?

MainActivity - Where I attempt connection:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new HTTPTask().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class HTTPTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        //location of file to retrieve
        String url = "http://192.168.x.xx/emenu/db_connect.php";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in Connection " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Established!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection initiating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

}

MANIFEST:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dbconnectiontest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your code, logcat and relevant stuffs?

Comment: @nOiAd Added my code above. I did not add Log cat because there is nothing in the log cat bar the error message I included in my question. The app doesn't actually crash, it just fails to connect and hangs.

Comment: Have you tried to call the same URL with the build in browser of your device? Does that work?

Comment: I have been facing this similar problem. some times my app works fine but some times it does not connect and throws same error. i cant figure it out yet .